# Remove first element of string if present in column with varying length data R

Tags: r, regex

I have a column with values like this:

```
id
26-2016-01-775
2006-01-4376-1
2007-01-4567
290-2016-01-56-2
```

I want to remove the prefix before the year (2016, 2006 etc) if present, and leave the rest. I have tried various regex patterns but can't seem to get the pattern right due to the varying length of the entries. Any suggestions?

I have tried the following:

```
gsub("^[[:alpha:]]_([20].*?)", "\\1", id)
```

But this doesn't capture the part to remove correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can match zero or more digits (`\\d*`) followed by a `-`, capture the 4 digits and the rest of the characters as a group and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^\\d*-?(\\d{4}-.*)", "\\1", df1$id)
#[1] "2016-01-775"    "2006-01-4376-1" "2007-01-4567"   "2016-01-56-2]"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("26-2016-01-775", "2006-01-4376-1", "2007-01-4567", 
"290-2016-01-56-2]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```